# How do I reference items that I add to Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

I am new to Visual Studio Tools For Office. I have been trying to run a macro that is inside an MS Access file. I added the Access file to the solution but I cannot figure out how to access it.

```
 Access.Application app = new Access.Application();
 app.Visible = true;       

 app.OpenCurrentDatabase("\\wfdb.accdb");
```

The last statement throws an exception because it cannot find the Access file.

How do I get the path of this file?

How do I reference items that I add to VS Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the location of the database files is under `C:\Users\Current_User\Documents\Database.accdb`
If it is not there open Access, go to `File`, in the right part of the screen you will see `View and edit database properties`. Go to `General`. there the `location` of the database will be shown.

Comment: I want to add this path programmatically. I will be publishing this so a hard coded path will only work on my system.